# How to implement basic data type for my Java project

Tags: java, c++

I normally work for C++. Now coding for Java, I know that Java doesn't have `typedef` and I have to implement my own object for my basic data type object as

```
public class FundamentalDataType<T> {
      public T x;
}
```

So T represents my basic data type and if T is Double, the whole project is using double, if Float the whole project is using Float.
But when I make another `Class` extending `FundamentalDataType`, I have error if I write as

```
public class Euclidean_Distance_Function extends FundamentalDataType<T>
```

if it is line

```
public class Euclidean_Distance_Function extends FundamentalDataType<Double>
```

That deviates my idea of making FundamentalDataType class. How can I implement that concept in Java?

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: Do you intend to have `Euclidean_Distance_Function` as a generic class?  If so, you'll need to put a `<T>` (or something) in its declaration.  If not, then you'll need to specify what `<T>` should be replaced with in the superclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the subclass is going to use the same data type of the superclass, declare it as:

```
public class Euclidean_Distance_Function<T> extends FundamentalDataType<T> 
{ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks. I have Double operator(final Pair<T> w, final Pair<T> x){} method. Inside has Math.pow((w.getFirst() - x.getFirst()). The error is T is undefined for Mat.pow. How to solve?

Comment: Try to cast it to a type that `Math.pow()` accepts. Try to do some more research and if you can't figure out the solution, post a new question. Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).